# how to extract part of URL in bash using regx?

Tags: string, bash, variable-expansion

I am trying to extract part of url using bash regex
. from below mentioned URL i just want to extract 124, which will always be between two hyphens .

```
http://abc-124-001.portal-ex.xyz-xyz.com:8091/
```

i tried doing following but i am looking for any better options to do this in one line

```
f=http://abc-124-001.portal-ex.xyz-xyz.com:8091/
f=${f#*-}
echo ${f%%-*}

op: 124
```

can this be done in one line or in any better way??

Comment: if all you want is a `one-liner` then consider: `f=${f#*-}; echo ${f%%-*}`

Comment: Do you need more help or is there a solution that you liked best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cut`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='htt''p://abc-124-001.portal-ex.xyz-xyz.com:8091/'
id=$(cut -d'-' -f2 <<< "$s")
echo "$id"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/dW2RDO).

Comment: Hi @Wiktor , How can i extract "abc-124" from host rather then just "124" ?

Comment: echo 'http://abc-124-001.portal-ex.xyz-xyz.com:8091'| cut -d"/" -f2 | cut -d"-" -f1

this doesn't work .. what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: envName=http://abc-124-001.portal-ex.xyz-xyz.com:8091   ...    
envName=${envName%%.*}    ...    
envName=${envName%-*}      ....
echo $envName | cut -d"/" -f3   ........
abc-124
....

can this be done in better way?

Comment: @deewreck There are many ways. Here is one: `id=$(cut -d'-' -f1,2 <<< 'htt''p://abc-124-001.portal-ex.xyz-xyz.com:8091/')` and then `echo "${id/http:\/\//}"`, or use `id=$(sed 's,.*://\([^-]*-[^-]*\).*,\1,' <<< 'htt''p://abc-124-001.portal-ex.xyz-xyz.com:8091/')` ([demo](https://ideone.com/p6Sjbv)).

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is not bad. Alternatively this can also be done using a regexp:

```
[[ $f =~ -([^-]+)- ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

It needs only "one step" for the extraction, while your approach needs two. However your glob patterns are simpler than my regex, so it is a matter of taste what you consider simpler.

Note that I didn't treat the case when the pattern does not match at all, simply since you also did not care about this case. It is trivial to add some error handling if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex matching:

```bash
if [[ $f =~ -([0-9]+) ]] ; then
    n=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo $n
else
    echo Cannot match in $f >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Or maybe `^[^-]+-([0-9]+)` to **not** match `124` in

```
http://abc-a-124-001.portal-ex.xyz-xyz.com:8091/
#          ~
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really a one-liner but almost:

```bash
$ f=http://abc-124-001.portal-ex.xyz-xyz.com:8091/
$ arr=(${f//-/ })
```

What you look for is `arr[1]`:

```bash
$ echo ${arr[1]}
124
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `read` with `IFS`

```bash
$ f=http://abc-124-001.portal-ex.xyz-xyz.com:8091/
$ IFS='-' read -ra parts <<< $f
$ echo "${parts[1]}"
124
$ declare -p parts
declare -a parts=([0]="http://abc" [1]="124" [2]="001.portal" [3]="ex.xyz" [4]="xyz.com:8091/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try awk:

```
$ echo "http://abc-124-001.portal-ex.xyz-xyz.com:8091/" | awk -F"-" ' { print $2 } '
124
```